# Delphi FireMonkey MapView show only blank map

Tags: android, google-maps, delphi, firemonkey

I'm building Android application which using TMapView component.
I inspiring by this article [Working with TMapView ...](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/working-with-the-new-mapview-on-ios-and-android-with-rad-studio-xe8)

I do this steps:

- Collect API key in Google Developer console
- Allow Map service Entitlement List
- Put API Key on field in version info card
- Allow Access network state

But in my application shown only blank map (gray square with google logo and +- zoom buttons)

MapView.MapType I tried Normall,Terrain, ... but it is same

Where can be a problem ?

Comment: Please post some code you've written first, so that we can help you.

Comment: There is no code needed. MapView must load default map. But I try
`MyLocation := TMapCoordinate.Create(48.15341,20.12475);
MapView1.Location :=  MyLocation;`
But no changes, map is blank

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure at Google Developer Console your Debug and Release certificate fingerprint.
This article teaches you to get and configure the fingerprints: [Configuring Android Applications to Use Google Maps](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Configuring_Android_Applications_to_Use_Google_Maps)

You can see at the image that I have some fingerprints configured, that's because we have more than one developer that compiles the project.

[image: Fingerprints]

Comment: but i have APIkey and I enable GoogleMaps Android API in Google developer console

Comment: @milenjao 
You have the API key, but you probably not configured the fingerprints. I had this problem when I was developing an app, which was only resolved when I made these settings. I edited my answer and post an image with my app configuration. Look the fingerprints.

Comment: but I have this things configurated
[![googleapi.png](http://s16.postimg.org/nqs0ks68l/googleapi.png)](http://postimg.org/image/dgplljgcx/)

Comment: Any ideas to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed now.
I have bad package name for debug certificate. I use com.embarcadero.MyAppName but correct package name is same as in Realse but there is different SHA-1 key

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem , i have solved it ..
I find that my APP's build setting is wrong, 
when i change :
Target Platforms (Android)->Android - Android SDK 24.x.x.x 32bit ->Configuration->Development
To: XXXXXX->Configuration->"Application Store", then google map is OK..
of course,  Provisioning of my project options ,Build Type: Android - Application Store , KeyStore File is the keystore i had created.